# django-social-auth facebook login keeps overwriting same user

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I implemented django-social-auth and got it to authenticate me with Facebook.

I would like it to also create a new user in the system, and write the email, name, and phone number if possible.

However, each time i log in with a user, it keeps overwriting the root user and not creating a new user?

I am also using a custom authentication module, and it's not creating a user in the custom model.

Settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'something.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'something.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    templatedir
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'frontpage',
    'social_auth',
    'django.contrib.admin'
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'something.auth_backends.CustomUserModelBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
)

CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL = '/newuser/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_REDIRECT_URL = '/disconnected/'
SOCUAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS = True

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'XXX'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = 'XXX'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email','user_birthday','user_hometown','user_location','user_about_me']


LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'social_auth_user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('twitter','facebook','google')

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXX'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXX'
```

URL's.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

from frontpage.views import LoginPage, FrontPageView
from frontpage import views
from django.contrib import admin


from social_auth import __version__ as version
from social_auth.utils import setting

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.LoginPage, name='LoginPage'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.loginreq, name='loginreq'),
    url(r'^newuser/$', views.newuser, name='newuser'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.HomePage, name='HomePage'),
    url(r'^jobs/offers$', views.jobsoffers, name='jobsoffers'),
    url(r'^jobs/view$', views.jobsview, name='jobsview'),
    #url(r'^home/$', FrontPageView.as_view(), name='front_list'),
    (r'^admin/jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),

    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'something.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^something/', include('something.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Views.py

```
class FrontPageView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'front_list'
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    queryset = classifield.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FrontPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['offers'] = offers.objects.all()
        return context

def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def LoginPage(request):
    classifield_list = classifield.objects.all()
    offers_list = offers.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("login.html", {'classifield_list': classifield_list,'offers_list':offers_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def HomePage(request):
    classifield_list = classifield.objects.all()
    ctx = {'last_login':request.session.get('social_auth_login_backend')}
    return render_to_response("homepage.html", {'classifield_list': classifield_list, 'ctx':ctx}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to anyone else who gest stuck with this:
DONT LOG IN TO THE ADMIN! 
Since you're logged in to the admin, it keeps overwriting your admin user.
Log out of the admin, and it will work!
Yeeey!